AWS keyspaces - Performance
I have 2 questions about AWS Keyspaces.

I have an important table 'posts' with this structure:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS social_platform.posts (
    id UUID,
    user_id UUID,
    title TEXT,
    content TEXT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP,
    content_media_url TEXT,
    user_username TEXT,
    user_first_name TEXT,
    user_last_name TEXT,
    user_profile_picture TEXT,
    user_role TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

Because AWS Keyspaces does not currently support materialized views or index I came up with a solution like this:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS social_platform.posts_user_id_lookup (
    id UUID,
    user_id UUID,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id), id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id ASC);


Now I am also able to search for user specific posts.
Does this makes sense performance wise or is there a better solution to allow querying for multiple keys?

Obviously the post should be ordered by created_at. Currently I have another lookup table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS social_platform.posts_created_at_lookup (
    date_partition DATE,
    id UUID,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY ((date_partition), created_at, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC, id ASC);

But with this structure I need to fetch it like this:
const pageSize = parseInt(req.query.limit as string) || 10;
const lastTimestamp = req.query.lastTimestamp ? new Date(req.query.lastTimestamp as string) : new Date();
const datePartition = lastTimestamp.toISOString().split('T')[0]; // YYYY-MM-DD
console.log('Date partition:', lastTimestamp);
let query = 'SELECT id FROM posts_created_at_lookup';
let params = [];

if (lastTimestamp) {
    query += ' WHERE date_partition = ? AND created_at <= ? ORDER BY created_at DESC, id ASC LIMIT ?';
    params = [datePartition, lastTimestamp, pageSize];
} else {
    query += ' WHERE date_partition = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC, id ASC LIMIT ?';
    params = [datePartition, pageSize];
}

const timeResult = await client.execute(query, params, { prepare: true });

const orderedIds = timeResult.rows.map(row => row.id);

if (orderedIds.length === 0) {
    return res.status(200).json([]);
}
const postsResult = await client.execute(
    'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id IN ?',
    [orderedIds],
    { prepare: true }
);

const orderedPosts = orderedIds.map(id =>
    postsResult.rows.find(post => post.id.equals(id))
);

const lastPost = orderedPosts[orderedPosts.length - 1];
const nextTimestamp = lastPost?.created_at || null;
console.log('Next timestamp:', nextTimestamp);

which to me does not seem very smart and fast.
But because this is a common practice, there has to be well designed logic already, right?


